# Java json extraction data

Tags: java, json

I have a data in this format.

```
{"responseData": {"results":[{"GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch",.......}],"cursor":{"resultCount":"16,900,000","pages":[........
```

I have put the full text into this first.

```
JSONObject fullResult = new JSONObject(text);//text represents my data.

JSONObject responseData1 = fullResult.JSONObject("responseData");
```

here I keep getting this "error: method getJSONObject in class JSONObject cannot be applied to given types;".

I need to extract just the value of resultCount. I keep getting stucked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method is called `getJSONObject( String )` i think

Comment: Can I directly access the "resultCount":"16,900,000"? I just need the value of 16,900,000?

Comment: @user2711681 No, it is nested in another JSON object. You need to get that JSON object first (and whatever else is in between).

Comment: Ok I got it JSONObject fullResult = new JSONObject(text);
  JSONObject responseData1 = fullResult.getJSONObject("responseData");
  JSONObject cursor1= responseData1.getJSONObject("cursor"); I guess this lead me till cursor am I right ?

Comment: @user2711681 Try it and see.

Comment: Yes it works I got it thank you System.out.println("\nJSON : "+cursor1.getString("resultCount")); but what is best mechanism to covert this string into big integer?

Comment: new BigInteger( string )